# How do I edit PDF files produced by LaTeX in Illustrator? Fonts are not found

Tags: fonts, pdf, illustrator

When I try to use Adobe Illustrator (CS4) to edit a PDF file produced by LaTeX with several equations in it, Illustrator complains that it can't find the fonts:

```
The font CMBX10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMMI10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMMI6 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMMI7 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMMI8 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMMIB10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMR10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMR7 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMSY10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMSY6 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font CMSY7 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
The font MSBM10 is missing.  Affected text will be displayed using a substitute font.
To preserve appearance, some text has been outlined.
```

How do I find & install the necessary fonts?

Comment: Off-topic, I'm afraid. Can we migrate this question to [su]?

Comment: Have you tried to copy those fonts into the system's font directory?

Comment: @doncherry: Even better: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Patrick.Gundlach: this may be insufficient. I think there is a font directory dedicated to Illustrator only once the latter is installed. It is better to drop the fonts you want to use within Illustrator in that folder. I could install the .pfb kpfonts family this way and use it in Illustrator but I cannot remember the exact path.

Comment: @doncherry: You're welcome to move this question wherever you'd like, but to me it seems like a pretty TeX-specific issue.

Comment: @doncherry: I would not consider this as off-topic. Basically, it is related to LaTeX font handling and the issue is a general one: What to do regarding fonts, if LaTeX is just a first step in a document production process (e.g., for those, who use TikZ for graphics).

Comment: I agree with @doncherry that this is off-topic. The OP's needs are so grotesque he can't possibly be a TeX user, which I would see as the only possible reason for keeping this question here

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Grotesque? How's that? Is that a typography pun? It seems like a pretty basic / straight-forward question to me.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Moving fonts

As Patrick Gundlach and pluton suggest, you can just make the fonts available to Illustrator. They're in your system's texmf, which you can find by running

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFDIST
```

For TeX Live 2011, `$TEXMFDIST` is by default at

- Windows: `C:\texlive\2011\texmf-dist`
- OS X: `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist`

All the `CM*` fonts are at `$TEXMFDIST/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm`, and the `MS*` fonts are at `$TEXMFDIST/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols`. You can install these as system fonts if you want to. But if you don't want to clutter your system fonts, you can copy all the `pfb` and `pfm` files to Adobe's [local font folder](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/fonts.html):

- Windows: `Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts`
- OS X: `Library/Application Support/Adobe/Fonts`

If you don't actually have TeX, there's also an incomplete collection of TeX fonts [here](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/images/4/45/TeX-Illustrator.sit).

### XeLaTeX

For easy compatability with Illustrator, you can use XeLaTeX and fontspec to write your LaTeX document in a font available to your system. For math, download a Unicode math font and use it with unicode-math.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times LT Std}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS-Math.otf}

\begin{document}
This is some text\par
This is some text with numbers 01234567\par
\[\left(\frac{\omega^2\rho}{\hat{\jmath}}\right)=\int \sqrt{\mathcal{M}(f)}\;dx\] 
\end{document}
```

Bonus: Your PDF will be tiny.
Downside: Math spacing issues introduced with unicode-math. Limited microtype support.

### Other solutions

If you want to *guarantee* that Illustrator won't mess up your LaTeX document's formatting...

[This page](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/Illustrator.html) suggests using Ghostscript to outline all text on the page:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=nofont-Myfile.ps -q -dbatch         -dNOPAUSE Myfile.pdf -c quit
```

You can also do that in Illustrator, as shown in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekVPPSsbiyc). But this means you can't edit the text – just reposition elements. It will also probably inflate your PDF's size quite a bit.

If you just want to draw on top of the LaTeX document, you can make a new PDF in Illustrator and *Place* the LaTeX PDF in the background, as in the first part of that video. Make your doodles, remove the background, save the PDF, and overlay it on one of your LaTeX document's pages using `\includegraphics`.

Comment: This is probably naive, but I'm sure it would help others too... where do I actually get those fonts?

Comment: TTF/OTF fonts are really standard. You can get them from a lot of places. See http://www.fontsquirrel.com, http://www.myfonts.com or many others...

Comment: @Raphink This question pertains to a specific set of fonts, which I could not find on either of those sites. (I did also do a cursory Google search, but could not find an archive containing the pfb and pfm files.)

Comment: @lid: On [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org).

Comment: Thanks, this answer [helped me](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239838/) to get the Libertine fonts to open in Illustrator.

Comment: If you're having this problem with matlab generated pdfs, you can find the fonts in `Applications/MATLAB_<distribution>/sys/fonts/type1/cm`

Comment: This also fixes the "dragging from LaTeXit to illustrator uses wrong font" problem.

Comment: I could kiss you right now.

Comment: If /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Fonts does not exist you can create it and it works.

Comment: Otherwise, you should be able to find it inside `/Users/<your_user>/Library/Application Support/Adobe`.

Answer (score 6):

***Moving fonts, Windows 10, CS6***

In Windows 10, using CS6, I could only find the fonts in Adobe Illustrator when putting the tex fonts into the folder below

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CS6 (64 Bit)\Support Files\Required\Fonts
```

In Windows 10, it did not work to paste the tex files into

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\FontsRecommended

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\FontsRequired
```

in the Common Files folder as suggested above.

Comment: Same issue for Illustrator CC on Windows 10; fonts copied to Common Files were not recognized. The suggested `\Support Files\Required\Fonts` did work.

Comment: At first I had the same issue. Illustrator CS6 in Windows 10 did no pick up the fonts I copied into the `Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts` folder (which I had to create) as described by Chel but when I copied the files also into the `\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts` Illustrator and also all other CS6 programs recognized the fonts. I did not recognize that I had a 32bit and a 64bit version of Illustrator installed at the same time.

Comment: (continued) Simply take care to copy into the correct folder structure, it was not necessary to copy the fonts directly into Illustrators Support Files folder as long as the Fonts folder is created just as Chel instructed.