# How can I convert TikZ to SVG on a Mac?

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg

I'd like to be able to convert a TikZ picture written in LaTeX, into an SVG file which I could load up in Inkscape, for some "tweaking". I have read the threads

[How can I produce a .svg file from a TikZ diagram?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71616/how-can-i-produce-a-svg-file-from-a-tikz-diagram)

[Maintaining layout of Tikz diagrams with TeX4ht (converting as single pictures)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35145/maintaining-layout-of-tikz-diagrams-with-tex4ht-converting-as-single-pictures)

but I have been unable to get a solution working. In particular, the following solution code to get TikZ to produce an svg file itself via the "tex4ht" option doesn't work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-tex4ht.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node[draw] (A) {A};
\path (2,0) node[draw] (B) {B};
\draw (A) -- (B) node[midway,above = 0 em] {via};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error from pdfLaTeX:

```
Undefined control sequence.  
\pgfsys@beginicture -> EndP \HtmlParOff ...
```

Comment: You can compile your `tikz` command to produce a `pdf` file and then you can open it with Inkscape.

Comment: Ok, but this mangles up the text, and math.

Comment: Well, if you have the fonts installed on your system to be used within Inkscape, no problem. I do this here. I can use, for example, `cmr` (Computer Modern Roman).

Comment: Ok thanks, how can I do that? Specifically, for Computer Modern Roman and the math fonts?

Comment: For example, http://www.monperrus.net/martin/using+computer+modern+type1+fonts+with+openoffice+on+linux

Comment: Those instructions are for Linux. I installed the fonts on Mac from <http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/files/>, but when I open a pdf with LaTeX text/math file in Inkscape it doesn't use the font.

Comment: [Here's my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79205/19372) to a similar question. This approach converts to `.ps` which I think Inkscape should open just fine.

Comment: @JimboBimbo Thanks, but seems a bit of a work-around. If the fonts are installed on my system, it should just be able to use them. I shoulnd't have to convert them to curves.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compile this document with `pdflatex`, you have to use some of `tex4ht` tools, like `htlatex`, for example.

Try this:

```
htlatex filename
```