# How can I make Illustrator recognize Linux Libertine fonts?

Tags: libertine, illustrator

I use MikTeX 2.9/pdfLaTeX on my Windows 7 machine to compile the following document, typeset in Linux Libertine font:

```
\pdfoutput=1
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\begin{document}
My text
\end{document}
```

The document compiles without errors and warnings. I need to edit this document (well, others like it) in Adobe Illustrator CS6, but when I open it, I get the error messsage:

```
Die Schrift LinLibertineT fehlt.  
Betroffener Text wird mit einer Ersatzschrift angezeigt.
```

Translated to English:

```
The font LinLibertineT is missing.
The affected text will be displayed with a replacement font.
```

I downloaded and installed [the TTF and OTF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/files/linuxlibertine/5.3.0/) fonts from the [Linux Libertine website](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/), but Adobe Illustrator still does not recognize the font. I poked around in the [Libertine package on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine), and there is a file called `LinLibertineT.pfb` that has a promising filename, but I could not figure out how to use it.

Is there a way to install the Libertine font in such a way that Adobe Illustrator can open my document?

Alternatively, I could try to use the fonts in a different way, for example by using XeTeX, but is not without problems itself (microtype). I would prefer persuading Illustrator to work with the current pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Libertine package [hosted on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine) has a folder called `type1`. This folder contains `*.pfb` files. While you cannot easily install these files with the Windows font manager, you [can copy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45268/32591) them to the [local font folder](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/fonts.html) of Adobe Illustrator. On my machine, I had to create this folder at  `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts`.

After copying the `*.pfb` files there, specifically the file `LinLibertineT.pdf`, I was able to import my pdf document.

Comment: Anyone have a solution on mac?

Comment: @AlecJacobson have you found a solution for Mac?